# Unable to install Maximo 7.5.0.7 Fix Pack after install Maximo 7.5 DEMO

Tags: x86-64, windows-server-2008-r2, websphere-7, maximo

I successfully installed Maximo 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit with the defaults (WebSphere 7, DB2, Tivoli Directory). I'm trying to install the 7.5.0.7 fix pack but get this error after I ran install_win64.bat (Run as Administrator). This error occurs a few steps after "Database is ready for upgrade" checkbox.

`CTGIN2076E: Exception Running WASThingClient method for task runConfigurationStep.`

The CCMD_install.log said:

```
FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: Getting a WAS thin client config task object
FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: Running WAS thin client config task
FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: Returned from running WAS thin client config task
FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: Got task result from task return.  

Completion message :CTGIN2076E: Exception Running WASThinClient method 
for task runConfigurationStep.

FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: verifyInputs method, 
rc=-1 cmpMessage=CTGIN2076E: Exception Running WASThinClient 
method for task runConfigurationStep. stderr=CTGIN2286E: 
An error occurred while configuring the WebSphere Application 
Server thin client. The error message is CTGIN2283E: Exception 
caught while connecting to the remote server. Exception 
com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.util.rxa.RemoteSystemException: 
com.ibm.tivoli.ccmdb.install.common.util.rxa.RemoteSystemException: 
Remote system cannot be reached using Supported RXA Protocols... stdout=

FndUpgradePanelActionshandleInstall: 
Configuration of WAS thin client was not successful
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure MXServer on the application server is stopped first.**

1. Extract the fix pack to c:\temp\ to run the installer.
2. From a command prompt, run:

   - C:\temp>`set skipwasvalidation=yes` (this will create a set variable
     to skip websphere application server validation)
   - On the same command prompt window run the `install.exe` (or
     `install_win64.exe` for x86-64).
3. When you run install.exe, the Run
       Configuration Step panel will offer the some options:

   - Check on Copy files now, but perform the installation configuration step later
   - Deploy application files manually later
   - Defer the Update of the Maximo Database

This will complete the install, deferring all automated actions.

4. At a command prompt, change to the c:\ibm\smp\scripts folder and run:

`taskrunner.bat CONTINUE STOPONERROR`

5. Run updatedb.bat from c:\ibm\smp\maximo\tools\maximo
6. Build and deploy the maximo.ear (c:\ibm\smp\maximo\deployments\buildmaximoear.cmd)

[Source: CTGIN2233E: The WebSphere NodeAgent is not running](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21515804)